# Excluding a dependency from a dependency

Tags: gradle

I'm working with gradle and although I've been using `exclude` with success to remove transitive dependencies I don't want, I can't seem to work out how to solve the following.

Let's assume I have the following dependencies:

```
org.library:useful:2.0.0
+--org.library:logging:1.5
+--org.another-library:tools:1.9
   +--org.library:logging:1.4
```

As you can see I have a version conflict between logging 1.5 and logging 1.4.  In my configuration I know that I can use exclude do the following:

```
config('org.library:useful:2.0.0') {
   exclude(group: 'org.library', module: 'logging')
}
```

But how do I say "`exclude logging 1.4"` that doesn't come from anything I depend on (in this example it comes from `org.another-library:tools:1.9`)?

Answer (score 1):

One way of dealing with the fact that you might have a dependency conflict and you want to always resolve it to a certain version is to use resolution strategy with forcing:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.library:logging:1.5'
  }
}
```

Also, note that in your example, 1.4 will be excluded anyway as Gradle by default picks the highest version if there is a [version conflict](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#version_conflicts).

Comment: Thanks @erdi, for your comment, I'm switching to using failOnVersionConflict() which will cause the build to fail in this situation.